# Adding a custom attribute to products in Shopify app and reflect attribute on product page

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, shopify-app, polaris

I have created an app on Shopify that lists the existing products of the user. The user can select a product and enter a string specific to the selected product. The string is a link that will lead them to another website. When they are done and click "Save", the link should be connected with the selected product.

**My question is**: In which of the product's attributes should I store the link? According to Shopify documentation, `metafield` seems like a promising attribute, but it offers no indication on whether this is the intended use case. (See attached image 1). Additionally, I would like for the link to mutatable and visible in a text input field when the users browse their own products.

**Bonus question**: I would like to know how to automatically add this link above the "Add to cart button" when a customer browses that product (only if the products has a link).

Thanks

[image]